# Using Ghostscript with Python

Tags: python, ghostscript, postscript

I've gotten pretty turned around trying to figure out how to write Postscript files through Python. I have the standalone Ghostscrip app installed on my computer and it works great. I can do all the sorts of drawing that I need to do (very simple stuff), such as:

```
GS> newpath 
GS> 1 1 moveto
GS> 1 1 lineto
GS> 1 91 lineto
GS> 91 91 lineto
GS> 91 1 lineto
GS> 1 1 lineto
GS> stroke
```

All this works. However I cannot figure out how to replicate a similar result going through python code. I want to be able to incorporate normal python code with postscript commands. I was able to install a python version of ghostscript using "pip install ghostscript". Where do I go from here? Any suggestions/tips would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If what you installed had documentation, the natural place to start would seem to be looking at that documentation. Also, the `examples` folder at https://gitlab.com/pdftools/python-ghostscript seems like a promising place to find examples that you can modify.

Comment: That project itself seems like a small one with essentially just a single developer. It is unlikely that you will find a lot of resources on using it. The code that you showed above looks very much like turtle graphics. If you want to do this sort of drawing in a more mainstream Python way, you could look into the [turtle module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/turtle.html). In contrast with the python interface with postscript, turtle is heavily documented and is featured in many tutorials, YouTube videos, etc.

Comment: can't you put all commands in file `myfile.ps` and run `ghostscript myfile.ps` ?

Comment: You can feed PostScript into Ghostscript using the run_string() Ghostscript API call. I can't tell you how (or indeed if) that's exposed with the ghostscript module you've installed because I know nothing about Python I'm afraid. However as furas says you could just write a PostScript program in a file on disk and then run that file through Ghostscript. I'm fairly sure the module must have that ability.